# Cant connect to a aws rds database I created via the AWS RDS console

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora

I created a RDS database via aws console. The database is built with aurora MySLQ.

The problem is that it does not create a database it creates a cluster with at least two instances

```
spring:
  datasource:
    reader:
      username: admin
      password: mypassword
      driver-class-name: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
      jdbcUrl: jdbc:mysql://cr-management-database-instance-1-us-west-2a.XXXXXXXXX.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com:3306/<Database name>
      pattern: get*,find*
    writer:
      username: admin
      password: mypassword
      driver-class-name: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
      jdbcUrl: jdbc:mysql://cr-management-database-instance-1.XXXXXXXXXX.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com:3306/<Database name>
      pattern: add*,update*
```

So I have a cluster cr-management-database
And  have two instances
cr-management-database-instance-1 and
cr-management-database-instance-1-us-west-2a
But the console does not create a DataBase name So I cant complete the URL.
I am used to working with ordinary DBs, does aurora MySLQ RDS have a database name. And how do you create in via the console.

Comment: Instructions for [creating a database instance and connecting to it.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_ConnectToInstance.html).

Comment: Thanks I worked through that. The problem is it does not give the pattern for a datasource. Its usually mysql://<end point>:3306/<database name> But all RDS gives me is the endpoint and  the port. I think I am using the wrong type of connection. Should not be usinng spring data source. But instead should use cloud:
  aws:rds

Comment: You construct the url `mysql://<end point>:3306/<database name>` yourself.

Comment: Yes I know I construct the url mysql://<end point>:3306/<database name> But when I create the data base via the AWS RDS console it does not have a field for database name.

Comment: You can provide the initial database name under Additional Configuration when creating the database instance. You can also click Create Database from the RDS > Databases console afaik.

Comment: Thanks, I found that out. Created it, still cant connect but now I think its more to do with the VPC. LOL they dont make the wiring up easy. i wish I could go back to where I spend most of my time writing code,  Now its 2 days code, and a lifetime trying to get the wiring up right.